# Multiple sessions: IMPORT from S3 to Redshift causing duplicated and missing rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, multithreading, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I ran into an issue where multiple sessions started creating duplicated data and missing rows when copying from s3 to redshift.

I created a test script that starts 5 sessions and runs these sequentially. The duplication is recreated here frequently.

I am curious where I am going wrong with my implementation of the copy from s3 to redshift.

Below is a code block of essentially the flow for getting from s3 and COPY/IMPORT into redshift.

```
LOGGER.debug('Importing into %s', tmp_table)
            cursor.execute('BEGIN;')
            cursor.execute('LOCK {schema}.{table} ;'.format(**sql_args))
            cursor.execute('CREATE TEMP TABLE {tmp_table} ( LIKE {schema}.{table} );'.format(**sql_args))
            LOGGER.debug('{s3file}'.format(**sql_args))
            cursor.execute('COPY {tmp_table} FROM \'s3://{bucket}/{s3file}\' CREDENTIALS \'aws_access_key_id={s3user};aws_secret_access_key={s3pwd}\' {copy_options};'.format(**sql_args))
            cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tmp_table}'.format(**sql_args))
            res = cursor.fetchall()

            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {tmp_table};'.format(**sql_args))
            LOGGER.debug('Dropping {tmp_table}'.format(**sql_args))
            cursor.execute('DROP TABLE {tmp_table};'.format(**sql_args))
            cursor.execute('END;'.format(**sql_args))
```

I have tried messing with LOCKs and adjusting to autocommit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying to understand the issue - you are running this code 5 times sequentially and getting duplicate data, right?  Wouldn't this be expected since you are COPYing the same S3 file 5 times?  Also it is not clear what you expect to achieve with the LOCK but be aware that autocommit mode will immediately release the lock as the transaction will end right away.

Comment: Essentially I am using a function that takes a list of rows, writes them to s3, then writes those to redshift. All numbers are different from different sessions at the time of writing. Assuming there is some race condition that is causing the first few connections to duplicate the reading/writing. The test script spins up 5 sessions starting at 0,20,40,60,80 and writes 20 numbers. When I read the redshift table at the end, usually one of those numbers is duplicated 4 times and there is missing numbers from the other starting integers.

Comment: So there are 5 separate S3 objects created by some external-to-redshift process?  After the run do these S3 objects contain the correct (continuous and non-repeating) values?  Does each of the 5 processes name the exact single S3 file (S3 key) to COPY?

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is which coherency domain the issue is occurring in.  Redshift and S3 each have their own, separate coherency systems that don't interact.  Plus there is whatever coherency processes that are in place for the writer of the S3 objects.  The issue as described could be in any of these or in the interactions between them.

Comment: Its essentially just an import functionality. It takes the text, writes it to a file, writes it to s3, writes it to redshift, then deletes the temp table. I suppose thats what I am trying to figure out as well. The data when it is read from the S3 file on multiple threads is printing the same numbers so my guess is that when the connection first happens, it is duplicating the reading from that file. I have tried even randomly sleeping threads to see if its just an issue with every session reading at the same time.

Comment: Do these sessions use different file names or is the same one repeated?  Does the COPY command use wildcarding (loading all the files from a "folder" vs the exact file name)?  S3 is an interesting beast - as a distributed system is has some coherency caveats to keep in mind like no read after update consistency.  Can you inspect the S3 object for the same duplicate & missing rows as you are seeing in Redshift?  Identifying where in the data system the issues are being introduced is key.

Comment: The same file name is repeated. When there is only one thread, there is no issue. Whenever the second session is introduced, is where the issues arise. The COPY command

`cursor.execute('COPY {tmp_table} FROM \'s3://{bucket}/{s3file}\' CREDENTIALS \'aws_access_key_id={s3user};aws_secret_access_key={s3pwd}\' {copy_options};'.format(**sql_args))`

then after the file gets written to tmp table, the code then writes to the final table:

`cursor.execute('INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {tmp_table};'.format(**sql_args))`

Comment: So this is a possible reason.  S3 have strong consistency for GET after PUT but only for NEW OBJECTS.  When you update the S3 file contents this can take a while for all other access paths into S3 to see the changes (like Redshift).  This is know and eventual consistency - sometime in the future things will match.  This usually takes less than 10 seconds but I've seen it be over an hour when S3 is slammed.  You would need to sleep during the thread, between the PUT and the COPY, to resolve this and even then you would never be sure that your sleep is always long enough (and it wastes time).

Comment: The best practice is to always use new file names in data pipelines to avoid this and get S3's strong consistency behavior.  For example you can just add a random number to the file name that is unique to each thread.

Comment: Okay I added a hex uuid to the filenames and this worked. No more dupes or missing rows. That makes sense that it isnt perfectly timed. thanks for the insight and the help!!

Comment: Good deal.  S3 is a great service but it does have its quirks